# Dúvida com relação a ponteiros em C

Tags: c, ponteiro, falha-de-segmentação

Estou escrevendo um programa que possuí 3 arquivos: algoritmos.h, algoritmos.c e main.c.

Esse programa possuí vários algoritmos de ordenação de vetor de inteiros. Com a intenção de deixar o programa mais flexível, o tamanho do vetor gerado automaticamente é definido pelo usuário: (código abaixo fica na main)

```
    case 5:
        printf("\nDigite quantos numeros deseja alocar.\n");
        scanf("%d", &tamanho);
        printf("\nDigite a faixa de geracao. EX: 0 ate 100, digite 100.\n");
        int faixa;
        scanf("%d", &faixa);
        tamanho = randomvetor(vetor, tamanho, faixa);
        break;
```

E aqui está a função random vetor:(código abaixo fica em algoritmos.c)

```
int randomvetor(int* vetor, int tamanho, int faixa){
int aleatorio;
vetor = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * tamanho);
for (int i = 0; i < tamanho; i++) {
    aleatorio = rand() % faixa;
    vetor[i] = aleatorio;
}
imprimirtudo(vetor, tamanho);
return tamanho;}
```

Ele gera o vetor aleatório e imprimi. O problema, é que ao voltar para main, por algum motivo que não sei o ponteiro para o vetor é perdido e o programa passa a considerar `vetor = null` novamente.

Alguém sabe a solução?

OBS: com vetor de tamanho e valores fixos os algoritmos funcionam normalmente.

Comment: Em C toda passagem de parâmetros é por valor. Note que na função o ponteiro para inteiro vetor está na pilha de parâmetros ao qual é atribuído o endereço da área alocada, não é o endereço do vetor existente na main.